# Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Significant Throttling of Intel i7 Processor

Tags: 20.04, intel, performance, cpufreq

I have not been able get to my new laptop (An HP ZBook 15 G2 with Intel Core i7-4810MQ Quad Core Processor 3.7 GHz) to keep from SIGNIFICANTLY throttling my processors on Ubuntu 20.04.

It originally started at under 400MHz. I tried changing the Governor settings for Intel-Pstate to performance, I tried disabling the governor on Grub. I found a bunch of suggestions online that were attempted.

My last attempt had me switch CPU Governors entirely to acpi-cpufreq Governor and setting that to performance or ondemand. This did have an effect, but now it's maximum frequency is set to 900MHz. I tried using cpufreq-set to manually change that as well with no success.

Any help would be appreciated because I've really had it with the performance issues. Are there other distros of Linux that don't have this issue?

Here is my current frequencies

[image: CPU Frequencies]

Here is the current cpufreq-info output, see how it's set to only be 900MHz

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.41%, 800 MHz:33.30%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.41%, 800 MHz:33.29%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.41%, 800 MHz:33.30%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.41%, 800 MHz:33.30%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 4:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 4
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 4
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.40%, 800 MHz:33.30%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 5:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 5
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 5
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.40%, 800 MHz:33.30%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 6:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 6
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 6
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.41%, 800 MHz:33.29%  (1746)
analyzing CPU 7:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 7
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 7
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 2.80 GHz, 2.80 GHz, 2.70 GHz, 2.50 GHz, 2.40 GHz, 2.20 GHz, 2.10 GHz, 1.90 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance, schedutil
  current policy: frequency should be within 900 MHz and 900 MHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 900 MHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 2.80 GHz:0.03%, 2.80 GHz:0.00%, 2.70 GHz:0.00%, 2.50 GHz:0.00%, 2.40 GHz:0.00%, 2.20 GHz:0.00%, 2.10 GHz:0.00%, 1.90 GHz:0.04%, 1.80 GHz:0.04%, 1.70 GHz:0.04%, 1.50 GHz:0.05%, 1.40 GHz:0.03%, 1.20 GHz:0.03%, 1.10 GHz:0.04%, 900 MHz:66.40%, 800 MHz:33.31%  (1746)
```

Result of Top

```
    top - 15:25:35 up 18 min,  1 user,  load average: 2.08, 1.00, 0.59
Tasks: 347 total,   3 running, 344 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 17.6 us,  3.1 sy,  0.0 ni, 77.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15928.5 total,  12274.0 free,   2032.8 used,   1621.7 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  13505.7 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                   
   4114 gary      20   0 2786772 412368 193164 R 103.9   2.5   0:52.76 Web Content                                                                                                                               
   2880 gary      20   0 4178028 302196 108200 S  26.6   1.9   0:25.29 gnome-shell                                                                                                                               
   2675 root      20   0  177540  50868  35228 R  12.9   0.3   0:08.97 Xorg                                                                                                                                      
   3855 gary      20   0  497652 236072 151040 S   9.9   1.4   0:07.00 GPU Process                                                                                                                               
   3820 gary      20   0 3277312 296956 149340 S   8.6   1.8   0:27.65 MainThread                                                                                                                                
   3998 gary      20   0  970876  51648  39000 S   5.6   0.3   0:02.07 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                           
   1543 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   4.3   0.0   0:06.06 irq/38-nvidia                                                                                                                             
    914 root      20   0   85048   2376   1980 S   1.7   0.0   0:11.86 cpufreqd                                                                                                                                  
   4274 gary      20   0   20712   4068   3148 R   1.3   0.0   0:00.10 top                                                                                                                                       
   2808 gary      20   0  162884   6508   5852 S   0.9   0.0   0:00.12 at-spi2-registr                                                                                                                           
    410 root      19  -1  248028 170684 168660 S   0.4   1.0   0:30.93 systemd-journal                                                                                                                           
    792 root      20   0    2540    780    716 S   0.4   0.0   0:00.46 acpid                                                                                                                                     
    852 syslog    20   0  224324   5456   3632 S   0.4   0.0   0:04.93 rsyslogd                                                                                                                                  
      1 root      20   0  168304  12372   8588 S   0.0   0.1   3:43.97 systemd                                                                                                                                   
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                                  
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                                    
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                                
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                      
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                              
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                               
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.69 rcu_sched                                                                                                                                 
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 migration/0                                                                                                                               
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                             
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                                   
top - 15:26:14 up 19 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.74, 1.05, 0.63
Tasks: 349 total,   2 running, 347 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.1 us,  1.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 83.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.2 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  15928.5 total,  12302.2 free,   2002.4 used,   1623.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   2048.0 free,      0.0 used.  13535.9 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                             
   4114 gary      20   0 2797012 393096 193164 R 108.6   2.4   1:34.14 Web Content                                                                                                                         
   3855 gary      20   0  497652 236072 151040 S   8.6   1.4   0:10.51 GPU Process                                                                                                                         
   3820 gary      20   0 3277312 295576 150120 S   6.6   1.8   0:31.47 MainThread                                                                                                                          
   1543 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   5.3   0.0   0:08.28 irq/38-nvidia                                                                                                                       
   2675 root      20   0  177540  50868  35228 S   2.3   0.3   0:11.07 Xorg                                                                                                                                
   3998 gary      20   0  971560  52260  39000 S   2.0   0.3   0:03.82 gnome-terminal-                                                                                                                     
   2880 gary      20   0 4178028 302340 108200 S   1.3   1.9   0:27.12 gnome-shell                                                                                                                         
    914 root      20   0   85048   2376   1980 S   1.0   0.0   0:12.53 cpufreqd                                                                                                                            
   4274 gary      20   0   20712   4068   3148 R   0.7   0.0   0:00.38 top                                                                                                                                 
      1 root      20   0  168304  12372   8588 S   0.3   0.1   3:44.05 systemd                                                                                                                             
    294 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.39 kworker/u16:3-events_power_efficient                                                                                                
    410 root      19  -1  248028 171144 169120 S   0.3   1.0   0:31.10 systemd-journal                                                                                                                     
    790 root      20   0  246884   7396   6500 S   0.3   0.0   0:00.47 accounts-daemon                                                                                                                     
    852 syslog    20   0  224324   5456   3632 S   0.3   0.0   0:05.01 rsyslogd                                                                                                                            
   3807 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.3   0.0   0:00.06 kworker/0:4-events                                                                                                                  
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kthreadd                                                                                                                            
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                                                                                                              
      4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                                                                                                          
      6 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
      9 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                                                                                                                        
     10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                         
     11 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.71 rcu_sched                                                                                                                           
     12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.03 migration/0                                                                                                                         
     13 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/0                                                                                                                       
     14 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                                                                                                             
     15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                                                                                                             
     16 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/1                                                                                                                       
     17 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.06 migration/1                                                                                                                         
     18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.07 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                         
     20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
     21 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                                                                                                             
     22 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/2                                                                                                                       
     23 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 migration/2                                                                                                                         
     24 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.10 ksoftirqd/2                                                                                                                         
     25 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.67 kworker/2:0-cgroup_destroy                                                                                                          
     26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/2:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
     27 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/3                                                                                                                             
     28 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/3                                                                                                                       
     29 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 migration/3                                                                                                                         
     30 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.05 ksoftirqd/3                                                                                                                         
     32 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/3:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
     33 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/4                                                                                                                             
     34 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/4                                                                                                                       
     35 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.09 migration/4                                                                                                                         
     36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.08 ksoftirqd/4                                                                                                                         
     37 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.38 kworker/4:0-events                                                                                                                  
     38 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 kworker/4:0H-kblockd                                                                                                                
     39 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/5                                                                                                                             
     40 root     -51   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 idle_inject/5
```

Results of ps auxc | grep -i therm

```
root         185  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   15:07   0:00 acpi_thermal_pm
```

Results of free -h

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.0Gi        11Gi        80Mi       1.6Gi        13Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Results of sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6

```
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
19.69   866 11218   45  10.86   0.00
19.75   866 10087   44  11.01   0.00
20.24   864 32081   44  10.98   0.00
19.89   865 9915    45  10.88   0.00
19.57   866 9581    44  10.84   0.00
19.51   867 28248   44  10.80   0.00
19.03   866 8652    45  10.77   0.00
19.19   867 29111   45  10.75   0.00
21.04   867 11219   45  10.92   0.00
21.17   870 10631   46  10.92   0.00
19.42   866 29364   45  10.81   0.00
19.50   867 8938    46  10.84   0.00
21.07   868 10832   44  10.90   0.00
19.96   867 30598   45  10.84   0.00
19.36   867 9359    45  10.83   0.00
20.50   868 52384   46  10.86   0.00
21.44   868 12888   46  10.90   0.00
19.73   800 1079    46  10.55   0.00
```

Result from sensors

```
BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          15.98 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +40.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +40.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +39.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +37.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +38.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +40.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp2:        +40.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp3:        +85.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp4:        +85.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp5:        +25.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
temp6:       +127.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)
```

Results from sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Results from dpkg -l *freq* | grep ii

```
ii  cpufreqd          2.4.2-2ubuntu3 amd64        fully configurable daemon for dynamic frequency and voltage scaling
ii  cpufrequtils      008-1.1        amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  indicator-cpufreq 0.2.2-0ubuntu3 all          CPU frequency scaling indicator
ii  libcpufreq0       008-1.1        amd64        shared library to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
```

Results from ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

```
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 03:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 18 14:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 19 15:00 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 03:35 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 30 16:43 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the machine is practically unusable with speeds this low.

Comment: I can help you with this, but I only use primitive commands and turbostat, never cpufreq-info and such. The first step would be to get turbostat (linux-tools-common package, I think) running always with these command line options: `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6`. By the way, when was the last time you cleaned the air vents and such in your LapTop?

Comment: Huh, that's quite odd that you should be having frequency issues with the i7 4810MQ. Normally it's the much newer and/or more obscure CPUs where you run into those issues. Is it *possible* that the CPU is thermal throttling? Can you check the die temp with the `psensor` program?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `top` and `ps auxc | grep -i therm` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Also what temps are your CPUs running at?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the requested information.

Comment: I don't believe the acpitz-acpi-0 temperatures. I do believe the turbostat processor package temperature number. I am not familiar with acpi_thermal_pm. Suggest you go back to the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver, and for a test, manually limit maximum CPU frequency via `echo 50 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` and gradually increase it, under heavy load, watching temperature with turbostat. i.e. learn your thermal characteristics via experiment. Then setup thermald accordingly. @heynnema might also have input.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I don't see where a process is throttling the CPUs. I do see heavy "Web Content" usage. Did you have a web browser running? The `cpufreqd` daemon process is probably is what is controlling your CPU speeds. Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *freq* | grep ii`, and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema - I added the requested information. Currently there is no local ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions folder

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Tell me, at least as a troubleshooting step, if it makes sense. The software can always be reinstalled at a later time. Report back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welp, it's fixed. I'm happy that the issue is fixed, but it's fixed mysteriously.

Attempting to try @Doug Smythie's answer and re-enabling the intel-pstate governor and rebooting, my processors are now working optimally with nearly full processing power.

All I had to do was /etc/default/grub file and change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_pstate=enable quiet splash"

Once I rebooted and tested my CPU speed, it was fine. Restarted a few times and it sticks.

The mystery is that this was the Governor I was using before and I couldn't get these results previously. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This solved the problem on regolith and a newer zbook with 10.th gen i7. Everyone with similar spec should use this, really helped.

Answer (score 3):

nothing helps on here.
20.04.

'cpufreq-set -r --governor performance' dosnt do nothing, non help remove the 'ondemand' either.

It just keep throttling.

Comment: In my case it was a hardware issue for a particularly hot running laptop that Ubuntu was not adjusting well for. The throttling eventually came back. I bought aftermarket coolers and everything I could do to try and keep it from happening but that HP Zbook had it's own hardware throttling, and it didn't play nicely with ubuntu.

Just do yourself a favor and switch machines, or find a way to keep the machine much cooler than it's initially set up to do.

Answer (score 2):

**cpufreq**

Results from dpkg -l *freq* | grep ii

```
ii  cpufreqd          2.4.2-2ubuntu3 amd64        fully configurable daemon for dynamic frequency and voltage scaling
ii  cpufrequtils      008-1.1        amd64        utilities to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
ii  indicator-cpufreq 0.2.2-0ubuntu3 all          CPU frequency scaling indicator
ii  libcpufreq0       008-1.1        amd64        shared library to deal with the cpufreq Linux kernel feature
```

- I suspect that these various cpufreq softwares are causing your throttling problem. Use prefs, or config files, to tailor your needs.
- Or, at least temporarily, uninstall these, and retest the performance of your computer.

`sudo apt-get purge cpufreqd cpufrequtils indicator-cpufreq libcpufreq0`

`reboot`

Comment: Agree. Get rid of all that stuff.

Answer (score 2):

[In Ubuntu 20.10 cpu clock fixed at 800MHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307773/in-ubuntu-20-10-cpu-clock-fixed-at-800mhz) this answer helped me to solve my issue
on Latitude E3410 with intel i7-10510U CPU in Ubuntu 20.04.

I just uninstalled the `thermald` using `sudo apt autoremove thermald` and everything started working again like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `thermald`. While I kept ist, `systemctl status thermald.service` showed that its not working due to thinkpad_acpi