# ALL CPU's stuck at 800Mhz ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, cpufreq, cpuinfo

Cpu's all stuck at 800Mhz

I type in **watch -n1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz"** (to see cpu's)

No matter what I do, I launch a large program and render an animation in Blender or use Octave to crunch numbers the CPU's don't go past 800Mhz

[image: img1]

```
Computer
Summary
Computer
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
Memory  16315MB (4407MB used)
Machine Type    Laptop
Operating System    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
User Name   rt (rt)
Date/Time   Mon 30 Aug 2021 02:33:09 PM EDT
Display
Resolution  1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Audio Devices
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
Audio Adapter   USB-Audio - USB Audio Device
Input Devices
Power Button    
Sleep Button    
Lid Switch  
Power Button    
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard    
USB Audio Device    
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad    
Logitech Anywhere MX    
Video Bus   
HDA Intel PCH Mic   
HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone   
HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:3    
HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:7    
HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:8    
HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:9    
HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm:10   
Printers (CUPS)
OfficeJet_Pro_6978  Default
SCSI Disks
TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208DB    
ATA INTEL SSDMCEAC12    
ATA ST1000LM014-1EJ1    
Operating System
Version
Kernel  Linux 5.4.0-81-generic (x86_64)
Version #91-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 19:09:17 UTC 2021
C Library   GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31
Distribution    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Current Session
Computer Name   sys76
User Name   rt (rt)
Language    en_US.UTF-8 ()
Home Directory  /home/rt
Misc
Uptime  20 minutes
Load Average    0.83, 1.37, 1.62
Available entropy in /dev/random    3649 bits (healthy)


rt@sys76:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq$ grep -r .
scaling_min_freq:800000
scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
scaling_governor:performance
cpuinfo_max_freq:3400000
related_cpus:0
scaling_cur_freq:798264
scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
affected_cpus:0
scaling_max_freq:2400000
cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
scaling_driver:intel_pstate
cpuinfo_min_freq:800000


rt@sys76:/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:           0.00 V  
curr1:         0.00 A  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +14.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)
```

As requested:

```
rt@sys76:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:23
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:27
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:38


rt@sys76:~$ for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu4/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu5/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu6/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied
bash: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu7/cpufreq/scaling_governor: Permission denied




 rt@sys76:~$ cpupower frequency-info --policy
analyzing CPU 0:
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.40 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output for `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*`. Also try changing governors, as root, `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done`

Comment: @DougSmythies I posted the info as requested.  How does one change the governors as root correctly?

Comment: I use the following Gnome tray extension in Ubuntu 20.04 https://github.com/martin31821/cpupower
There are some prerequisites there, perhaps start with going through that prerequisite list as I think thats what is required to control the frequency.

Comment: If you do `sudo su` first your will become root. Then execute the command. I only use primitive commands.

Comment: @DougSmythies  I get an error
when I type in:
`sudo for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done`
The error I get is `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: You do it in two steps. First step `sudo su`, and you will end up with the prompt of "#" instead of "$", Then do `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done`.

Comment: With a package temperature of 50 degrees for a load average of 0.83 you likely have a thermal problem and your system is getting locked up at low CPU frequency. With the performance governor it might not ever update the pstate request register (although I thought that was fixed). Changing governors might kick it out. With a load average of 2.00 my processor package temperature is 34 degrees.

Comment: @DougSmythies I got rid of all the cpu managing extensions and rebooted then everything started working again...Something must have been conflicting

Comment: I suggest you continue to monitor things with turbostat (linux-tools-common package). Say this `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 6`. You might find you need some sort of thermal management. I run that turbostat command pretty much always..

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Ubuntu 20.04 and i7 chips...again

https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/Intel-CPU-CONSTANTLY-Throttled-to-Lowest-Frequency-Ubuntu-20-04/td-p/1253691

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268454/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-significant-throttling-of-intel-i7-processor

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you can make your CPU go at max speed:**

*Make a file named cpumaxspeed.sh or any name that you like and enter in this code:*

```
#!/bin/bash
#Getting and setting variables

echo Getting info....

CPUMIN=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq)
CPUMAX=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq)
CPUMAXGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMAX / 1000000" | bc)
CPUMINGHZ=$(echo "scale=1; $CPUMIN / 1000000" | bc)

#Display min and max CPU frequency in MHz
echo CPU min frequency: $CPUMIN" MHz" / $CPUMINGHZ" GHz"
echo CPU max frequency: $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"

#Setting CPU governor
echo Setting governor to performance
sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
echo Set governor to performance

#Setting to max frequency
echo Setting CPU frequency to be $CPUMAX" MHz" / $CPUMAXGHZ" GHz"
sudo cpufreq-set -r -f $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"
echo Set CPU frequency to $CPUMAXGHZ"GHz"

done
```

**To execute the file run this command:**

```
sudo sh yourfilename.sh
```

Replace [yourfilename] with the name that you entered.