# Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Significant Throttling of Intel i7 Processor

Tags: kernel, intel, cpu

I would really like to find out why my cpu's keep reverting back to a cpu powersave mode after I get a kernel update then reboot.

I cleaned my laptops vent but this seems to happen whenever a new kernel is updated and installed.

I type in **watch -n1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz"** (to see cpu's)

[image: pic 1]

```
s-tui (s-tui command output below)
```

[image: pic2]

```
    rt@sys76:~$ dpkg -l *freq* | grep ii
    rt@sys76:~$ 
    
    
    rt@sys76:~$ sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 6
    
    Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt GFXWatt
    2.95    800     3347    47      2.16    0.01
    2.76    800     3069    49      2.15    0.01
    5.85    800     5122    48      2.73    0.01
    11.87   800     8008    47      3.41    0.04
    8.23    800     5778    47      2.86    0.05
    
    rt@sys76:~$ lscpu
    Architecture:                    x86_64
    CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
    Byte Order:                      Little Endian
    Address sizes:                   39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    CPU(s):                          8
    On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
    Thread(s) per core:              2
    Core(s) per socket:              4
    Socket(s):                       1
    NUMA node(s):                    1
    Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
    CPU family:                      6
    Model:                           60
    Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Stepping:                        3
    CPU MHz:                         798.103
    CPU max MHz:                     3400.0000
    CPU min MHz:                     800.0000
    BogoMIPS:                        4788.65
    Virtualization:                  VT-x
    L1d cache:                       128 KiB
    L1i cache:                       128 KiB
    L2 cache:                        1 MiB
    L3 cache:                        6 MiB
    NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-7
    Vulnerability Itlb multihit:     KVM: Mitigation: Split huge pages
    Vulnerability L1tf:              Mitigation; PTE Inversion; VMX conditional cache flushes, SMT vulne
                                     rable
    Vulnerability Mds:               Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
    Vulnerability Meltdown:          Mitigation; PTI
    Vulnerability Spec store bypass: Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
    Vulnerability Spectre v1:        Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitizatio
                                     n
    Vulnerability Spectre v2:        Mitigation; Full generic retpoline, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIB
                                     P conditional, RSB filling
    Vulnerability Srbds:             Mitigation; Microcode
    Vulnerability Tsx async abort:   Not affected
    Flags:                           fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat p
                                     se36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdp
                                     e1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xto
                                     pology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds
                                     _cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 m
                                     ovbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm ab
                                     m cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shado
                                     w vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 s
                                     mep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flu
                                     sh_l1d
    rt@sys76:~$ 
    
    
    
    
    
        rt@sys76:~$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct:100
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct:23
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo:1
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/num_pstates:27
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/status:active
        /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/turbo_pct:38
        
        rt@sys76:~$ sensors
        BAT0-acpi-0
        Adapter: ACPI interface
        in0:           0.00 V  
        curr1:         0.00 A  
        
        coretemp-isa-0000
        Adapter: ISA adapter
        Package id 0:  +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
        Core 0:        +47.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
        Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
        Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
        Core 3:        +46.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
        
        acpitz-acpi-0
        Adapter: ACPI interface
        temp1:        +14.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)









rt@sys76:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.079
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.108
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 2
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.103
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 4
initial apicid  : 4
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 3
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.114
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 6
initial apicid  : 6
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 4
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.405
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 5
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.234
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 6
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.202
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 2
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 5
initial apicid  : 5
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 7
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 60
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping        : 3
microcode       : 0x28
cpu MHz         : 798.235
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 8
core id         : 3
cpu cores       : 4
apicid          : 7
initial apicid  : 7
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs            : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips        : 4788.65
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

rt@sys76:~$ 


rt@sys76:~$ grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*
grep: cat: No such file or directory
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/affected_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq:3400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq:800000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_transition_latency:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/related_cpus:0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors:performance powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq:798109
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver:intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor:performance
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq:2400000
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq:1615686
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed:<unsupported>
rt@sys76:~$ 


rt@sys76:~$ echo 85 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
[sudo] password for rt: 
85
rt@sys76:~$ echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct
100
rt@sys76:~$ sudo su
root@sys76:/home/rt# for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done
```

**kern.log**

```
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.394389] mce: CPU0: Thermal monitoring enabled (TM1)

Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.608061] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 8 devices
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611443] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611445] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611448] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611449] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611451] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'

Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    1.006274] thermal LNXTHERM:00: registered as thermal_zone0
```

**syslog**

```
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.

Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 thermald[1471]: 13 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3c:3 (6:60:3)
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 thermald[1471]: 13 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:3c:3 (6:60:3)
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 thermald[1471]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 thermald[1471]: sensor id 5 : No temp sysfs for reading raw temp
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 thermald[1471]: message repeated 2 times: [ sensor id 5 : No temp sysfs for reading raw temp]

Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611443] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611445] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611448] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611449] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
Sep 27 16:27:55 sys76 kernel: [    0.611451] thermal_sys: Registered thermal
```

Requested inormation link (was very large couldn't post here):
https://pastebin.com/px7zci4x

Other links I've found but it didn't solve the problem:

https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/Intel-CPU-CONSTANTLY-Throttled-to-Lowest-Frequency-Ubuntu-20-04/td-p/1253691

[Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS Significant Throttling of Intel i7 Processor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268454/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-significant-throttling-of-intel-i7-processor)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/632339/intel-cpu-constantly-throttled-to-lowest-frequency-ubuntu-20-04

[Intel Core i7-8550U cpu frequency drops on high loads on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1329587/intel-core-i7-8550u-cpu-frequency-drops-on-high-loads-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1139270/1222991)? It’s a few years old, but may resolve the issue 

Comment: @matigo Yes I tried that and it didn't help, it's starting to happen regularly when they update the kernel and I need to reboot.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. There is very little CPU utilization in your examples, so I would expect a low CPU frequency. Perhaps show us your turbostat output with some load. show us also the output for `grep . cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/*`

Comment: @DougSmythies added the requested information to the question.  The problem is when I use Octave or Blender (which is often) to do rendering or number crunching the computer becomes unusable even the mouse.  The cpu speed is stuck at 800mhz it's very noticeable.

Comment: try this: `echo 85 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` and then `echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. While it will seem counter-intuitive, also try the powersave governor as root (`sudo su` first, get a # prompt): `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor; do echo "powersave" > $file; done`. Do you have any thermal related log entries in /var/log? Say `kern.log` or `syslog`?

Comment: @DougSmythies ok I added the information to document

Comment: I'll be away today. Check for [clock modulation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624937/my-cpu-slows-down-after-a-while-and-does-not-recover/664333#664333) and perhaps do a test with the thermald service disabled, being very careful of processor temperature, using max_perf_pct to limit heat manually.

Comment: @DougSmythies ok thanks for your help.  Here's the info from the link.  https://pastebin.com/px7zci4x

Comment: What make and model of computer? What kernel version? What do you get for `sudo rdmsr 0x1FC`?

Comment: @DougSmythies ok I get `4005d` , System-manufacturer :  `System76, Inc.`
System-product-name :  `Gazelle Professional, `
`Linux version 5.4.0-88-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-008) (gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04)) #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Sep 23 17:29:00 UTC 2021`

Comment: You could try setting bit 0 of 0x1FC to 0, meaning `sudo wrmsr 0x1fc 0x4005c`, but be careful as it disables an external throttling signal.

Comment: It would be good to see the turbostat startup spew, without the --quiet command line option.

Comment: Another ubuntu update came over and I applied it rebooted and the problem went away....I really would like to know why this keeps happening...