# Ubuntu 20.04 Multicore CPU scaling/frequency issues on i7-10510U

Tags: 20.04, intel, cpu, scaling, multi-core

Firstly, I will state my specs:

Intel i7-10510u with Intel UHD 620 graphics, AMD Radeon 610 dGPU, 256 GB Kioxia SSD,8GB RAM

I have a Dell Vostro 3590.

From my observations, individual cores do boost all the way to 4.9 GHz and when under a multicore task(like video encoding on handbrake), the frequency it stabilises at after a few minutes is 2.6-2.7 GHz after throttling on Windows. The problem I see in Ubuntu is that only the base frequency (which is 1.8 GHz) is reached under a multicore task for all cores. The monitoring software I use is powertop, and I have tlp installed on the laptop as well. I know it is not a problem with either of them, because the issue existed before I installed those two packages.

All the solutions I have seen online involve disabling stuff to do with Intel SpeedStep in the UEFI (which made no difference) and also installing cpufrequtils, which I doubt will work because I don't think you are able to edit the base frequency due to lack of permissions even as a superuser(correct me if I'm wrong).
From what I have read, this could be caused by the scaling driver on the linux kernel.

Some solutions include changing the power management settings on the Dell proprietary software on Windows, but unfortunately, this did not work either.

And no, it is not overheating, the temperature is about 60 degrees celsius under load, which is 15 degrees above idle. There is one thing I have noticed though, and it is that it runs at normal multicore speed for maybe about 5 seconds, where it does hit 90 degrees according to lm-sensors but then it retards the speed down to the base frequency. The processor is not supposed to throttle until it hits 99-100 degrees Celsius for my model (which is too hot, but hey, intel is gonna intel).

Is there anything that I can try to get Intel Turbo Boost to work with multicore tasks as well instead of just each individual core only?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, some program is wise and modern enough to use multicores for its operation and some are not large or not efficient to split an operation.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka I actually managed to solve this problem by getting rid of the thermald package, referring to the last answer on this thread https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268454/ubuntu-20-04-1-lts-significant-throttling-of-intel-i7-processor. The first answer did not work for me. I have Dell laptop of the same generation, so there may be shared mechanisms in the BIOS for controlling processor speed. I'm not sure if you completely understood my question, but thank you for the answer regardless!

Comment: I am not sure that I completely understand how it works, but some old design program based on 32 bit computing is using only one cpu at a time. `cpufreq` is a good idea. You can also try cooking down with a ventilator sending air bottom of the laptop, it will do. Anyway, glad that you find a way.